# Java - reading .txt file to arrayList omits last iteration and shows error

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java-io

I have a .txt file and require its contents to be put into an arraylist. 
It is in the following format, Each element(int,String) being on a new line within the document.

int number of parts
string partname
string description
int price
string partname
string description
int price
etc.

Whenever i run my program it will add the first however many attributes, but will not add the last three attributes to the arraylist.

```
    public static void loadPartsCleanly(){  

    try {
    //  java.io.File file = new java.io.File("parts.txt");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("parts.txt"));
        ArrayList<Part> partlist = new ArrayList<Part>();

        String name=null;
        String description = null;
        double price =0.0;
        int totalParts = 0;

        totalParts = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
    //totalParts ++ ;

        System.out.println(totalParts);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalParts; i++)
        {           
        //ArrayList<Part> partlist = new ArrayList<Part>();
             name = in.nextLine();
             description = in.nextLine();
             price = in.nextDouble();
             in.nextLine();

        int quantityInStock = 5;


        partlist.add(new Part(name, description, price, quantityInStock));

        System.out.println(partlist);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to locate the parts.txt file for opening.");


    } catch (Exception otherExc) {

        System.out.println("***** An unexpected error has occurred *****");
        otherExc.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

so in the above code it reads the first Int in the text document and assigns it for use in the for loop.

```
    totalParts = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
    //totalParts ++ ;

        System.out.println(totalParts);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalParts; i++)
```

The loop works fine up until the last part needs to be added to the arraylist, regardless of whether totalParts is 8 or 20.

Which gives this error..

> An unexpected error has occurred  java.util.NoSuchElementException: No
>   line found

I have been trying to figure this out but increasing frustration has prompted me to post on here, so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. If you need clarification with anything regarding my question, please ask.

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: string name  
string description
int price
string name
string description
double price
etc

Comment: It would be great if you post your input file with 2 parts.

Comment: Sorry its automatically formatting my comment onto one line, but each String/Int is on a new line in the document

Comment: could you post the exact exception as it is shown? Also how do you know *The loop works fine up until the last part needs to be added to the arraylist,*?

Comment: [Flash Drive Ultra Slim 16GB External 104.5 5, Handyscan Scanner  SkyPix Portable Easy Handheld Memory Card 65.8 5, Notebook Computer 32 GB RAM IBM Wireless 25.5 5, Samsung Monitor 24X46 Flat LCD screen 872.2 5, iPad Apple 32GB RAM  2324.5 5, Tab 10.0 Tablet Samsung Galaxy 401.2 5, Intel Chipset ATX Graphics Technology in an integrated GPU 230.0 5]......there is another part in the file that should be read

Comment: Sorry the input file is in the format .......... Int numberOfParts, string name, string description, double price

Comment: I think the last line of your input file parts.txt is a number, right? Try appending a line at the end of your file and run your program again.

Comment: @HowardWang Yes the last line will always be a number (double price). Unfortunately iam not allowed to change the txt file, i already had but my teacher said that it has to be used as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last line of your input file is a number.
What I saw from your code is that you use `nextDouble` to read the price and then you use `nextLine` to go to next line.
In such situation, if there is no more line behind the last number, you got error.

The following code solves your problem.

```
if (i + 1 < totalParts) {
    in.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `nextInt()` and `nextDouble()` methods are different than `nextLine()`. `nextLine()` reads the *\n* but the others.

So, if you have each element in a different line, you should use `nextLine()` always and then parse that line to the type that you want, for example:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
double price = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Iam not sure i understand exactly what your saying though. Is that within the for loop??

Comment: I mean that you should use nextLine() for all your parameters (not nextDouble()). That's because when you use nextDouble() the "pointer" of the Scanner is just before the \n, and the next execution of nextLine() reads just the \n next to your double. Hope I've explained it

Comment: Yes, but then you can convert it to a double with: `double price = Double.parseDouble(lineString);`